# Hide a ADBannerView. Is it ok to move it offscreen?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, applet, ads, iad

When the user changes screen, I want to hide the current ADBannerView . Is there a "right" way to do that? If I move it offscreen for instance, is it fine: I was wondering if it could keep serving ads while not being displayed and then I would break some Apple Agreement.

Is it also OK to cover an Ad with a modal view?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if the banner view is "clever" enough to realise when its offscreen, as if its not, it will matter because you get money for views as well as clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move it offscreen. It will detect that.

Answer (score 3):

Apple recommends moving it offscreen. Watch the 2010 WWDC session 112 video on iAd integration.